# cannot get boost graph object deserialized

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost graph library. I need to serialize a 
graph object and read it out later. But I found my 
program can't work properly with XML archiver. It 
always throws exception saying:

> XML start/end tag 
>   mismatch - position.

I did not define a tag named 
`"position"` in my serialization code. I don't know how 
to solve it. Here is a demo 
of the problem.

#### types.h

```
#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H

#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/deque.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

using namespace boost;
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

class QTable; //forward declaration
typedef QTable Eligibility;

//è§‚æµ‹ç±»åž‹
enum Observation{present,absent,idle};

//1ï¼‰å›¾æ¨¡åž‹çš„å®šä¹‰
enum vertex_BatteryLevel_t {vertex_BatteryLevel};
enum vertex_ObservationHistory_t {vertex_ObservationHistory};
enum edge_QFunction_t {edge_QFunction};
enum edge_Eligibility_t {edge_Eligibility};

namespace boost {
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(vertex,BatteryLevel);
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(vertex,ObservationHistory);
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(edge,QFunction);
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(edge,Eligibility);
}

typedef property<vertex_BatteryLevel_t,int,
    property<vertex_ObservationHistory_t,std::deque<Observation>,
        property<vertex_index_t,int>
    > 
> vertex_state;
typedef property<edge_QFunction_t,QTable,
    property<edge_Eligibility_t,Eligibility>
> edge_qfunction;
typedef adjacency_list<
    vecS,setS,directedS, //ç»“ç‚¹ç”¨vecSå› ä¸ºæ— éœ€åŠ¨æ€æ”¹å˜ç»“ç‚¹ä¸ªæ•°ï¼Œç”¨setSè¡¨ç¤ºè¾¹ä¸ºäº†å¼ºè°ƒæ˜¯ç®€å•å›¾ï¼ˆä¸¤ä¸ªç»“ç‚¹ä¹‹é—´ä¸€ä¸ªæ–¹å‘çš„è¾¹åªèƒ½æœ‰ä¸€æ¡ï¼‰
    vertex_state, //èŠ‚ç‚¹çš„ç”µé‡å’Œè§‚æµ‹åŽ†å²
    edge_qfunction  //æ¯ä¸ªæœ‰å‘è¾¹å¯¹åº”ä¸€ä¸ªublas::matrix<double>å¯¹è±¡å±žæ€§ 
> Graph;

//2ï¼‰Qå‡½æ•°çš„å®šä¹‰
//è¡Œä¸ºç±»åž‹
enum NotSensing{off=-2,recharge=-1};
typedef variant<int,NotSensing> Action; //action={å„ä¸ªæ–¹å‘,off,recharge}

//state=<åŽ†å²è§‚æµ‹,ç”µæ± ç”µé‡>
struct Status {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar,const unsigned int version);

    //ä»Žç»“ç‚¹id->è§‚æµ‹åŽ†å²çš„æ˜ å°„
    //æ¯ä¸€ä¸ªæ—¶åˆ»çš„åŽ†å²è§‚æµ‹é¡ºåºæ˜¯ä¼ æ„Ÿå™¨æœ¬èº«ï¼ŒæŒ‰ç…§è¿­ä»£å™¨é¡ºåºçš„å…¶ä»–ä¼ æ„Ÿå™¨è§‚æµ‹
    typedef std::map<int,std::deque<Observation> > HistoryType;
    HistoryType history;
    int batteryLevel;       //ç”µæ± ç”µé‡
    Status() {}
    Status(const HistoryType & h,const int & bl);
    Status(const Status & s);
    ~Status() {}
    friend bool operator<(const Status & idx1,const Status & idx2);
    friend bool operator==(const Status & idx1,const Status & idx2);
};

template<class Archive>
inline void Status::serialize(Archive & ar,const unsigned int)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("history",history);
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("batteryLevel",batteryLevel);
}

struct QTableElem {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &,const unsigned int) {}
    Status status;
    Action myaction, youraction;
    double value;
    QTableElem(const Status & s,const Action & ma,const Action & ya,double v)
    : status(s),myaction(ma),youraction(ya),value(v) {}
};

typedef QTableElem EligibilityElem;

//å› ä¸ºtypedefä¸èƒ½circular dependentæ‰€ä»¥éœ€è¦å®šä¹‰ä¸ªç±»ç»§æ‰¿å…¶ä¸­ä¸€ä¸ªtypedefã€‚
class QTable : public bmi::multi_index_container <
    QTableElem,
    bmi::indexed_by <
        bmi::ordered_unique<
            bmi::composite_key<
                QTableElem,
                bmi::member<QTableElem,Status,&QTableElem::status>,
                bmi::member<QTableElem,Action,&QTableElem::myaction>,
                bmi::member<QTableElem,Action,&QTableElem::youraction>
            >
        >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::member<QTableElem,Status,&QTableElem::status> >
    >
> {};

namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {
        template<class Archive> inline void save_construct_data(Archive & ar,const QTableElem * e,const unsigned int) {
            ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("status",e->status);
            ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("myaction",e->myaction);
            ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("youraction",e->youraction);
            ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("value",e->value);
        }
        template<class Archive> void load_construct_data(Archive & ar,QTableElem * e,const unsigned int) {
            Status s;
            Action ma,ya;
            double v;
            ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("status",s);
            ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("myaction",ma);
            ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("youraction",ya);
            ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("value",v);
            ::new(e) QTableElem(s,ma,ya,v);
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

#### types.cpp

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "types.h"

Status::Status(const Status::HistoryType & h,const int & bl)
:history(h),batteryLevel(bl)
{
}

Status::Status(const Status & s)
:history(s.history),batteryLevel(s.batteryLevel)
{
}

bool operator<(const Status & idx1,const Status & idx2)
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    assert(idx1.history.size() == idx2.history.size());
#endif
    Status::HistoryType::const_iterator it,it2;
    for(it = idx1.history.begin(), it2 = idx2.history.begin() ; it != idx1.history.end() && it2 != idx2.history.end() ; it++,it2++) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        assert(it->first == it2->first);
        assert(it->second.size() == it2->second.size());
#endif
        std::deque<Observation>::const_iterator itt,itt2;
        for(itt = it->second.begin(), itt2 = it2->second.begin() ; itt != it->second.end() && itt2 != it2->second.end() ; itt++,itt2++) {
            if(*itt < *itt2) return true;
            if(*itt > *itt2) return false;
        }
    }
#ifndef NDEBUG
    assert(it == idx1.history.end() && it2 == idx2.history.end());
#endif
    return false;
}

bool operator==(const Status & idx1,const Status & idx2)
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    assert(idx1.history.size() == idx2.history.size());
#endif
    Status::HistoryType::const_iterator it, it2;
    for(it = idx1.history.begin(), it2 = idx2.history.begin() ; it != idx1.history.end() && it2 != idx2.history.end() ; it++,it2++) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        assert(it->first == it2->first);
        assert(it->second.size() == it2->second.size());
#endif
        std::deque<Observation>::const_iterator itt,itt2;
        for(itt = it->second.begin(), itt2 = it2->second.begin() ; itt != it->second.end() && itt2 != it2->second.end() ; itt++,itt2++) {
            if(*itt != *itt2) return false;
        }
    }
#ifndef NDEBUG
    assert(it == idx1.history.end() && it2 == idx2.history.end());
#endif
    return true;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include "types.h"

//compile with "g++ main.cpp types.cpp -I. -o test -lboost_serialization"

int main()
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    {
        //load vertices
        std::ifstream in("../graph.txt");
        if (false == in.is_open())
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid graph model file!");

        typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertices_size_type size_type;
        size_type n_vertices;
        in >> n_vertices;
        std::istream_iterator<std::pair<size_type, size_type> > input_begin(in), input_end;
        Graph g(input_begin, input_end, n_vertices);
        //serialize the graph object
        {
            std::ofstream out("../test.xml");
            if (false == out.is_open()) throw std::runtime_error("invalid file!");
            boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(out);
            oa << make_nvp("graph", g);
        }
    }

    {
        //deserialize from the file
        std::ifstream xml("../test.xml");
        if (false == xml.is_open())
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid file!");
        {
            boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(xml);
            Graph g;
            try {
                ia >> make_nvp("graph", g);
            }
            catch (boost::archive::archive_exception const& ae)
            {
                std::cout << "Error: " << ae.code << ":'" << ae.what() << "'\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace std {
    template <typename T> istream & operator>>(istream & in,pair<T,T>& p) {
        in >> p.first >> p.second;
        return in;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you implement this in C++. Usually, performance would be the decree. I'd note that the use of multi-index containers as edge properties as well as XML serialization would run counter to such goals. I'm pretty sure the average Python solution would be _faster_ than this contrived datastructure.

Comment: C++ is the only programming language I learned in university. I will find better solutions in other languages. Which library do you recommend for graph and multi-index container representation in Python?

Comment: @breadbread1984 Also for future reference, you should post a minimal version of the code here, not link to an external site where you delete the code later - it destroys the effectiveness of this site and makes the question incomplete

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf I recovered the bits from my source control. The comments are garbled but that's how my editors showed them from the start. I did refactor the `main` function a bit to make it clearer what code did what.

Comment: thanks for that @sehe, i assume the comments were probably UTF-8

edit: nevermind seems they were in a weird encoding

Comment: @Eiyrioü von Kauyf I will paste the code here directly. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @sehe thanks for pasting the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always

- start small, build incrementally and **test** at each step.

In case of unexpected failure:

- eliminate causes (divide and conquer).

Had you done this, you'd have quickly found that even

```
Eligibility e;
oa << make_nvp("e", e);
```

followed by

```
ia >> make_nvp("e", e);
```

would have shown the **exact** same problem without even any data. The problem is `QTable` *derives* from a `boost::multi_index_container`, which breaks the serialization implementation for it.

Here's the minimal reproducer **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad05f6b2d305ab1d)</kbd>**

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

struct QTableElem {
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar,const unsigned int) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("dummy", dummy);
    }
    int dummy;
};

class QTable : public bmi::multi_index_container<
    QTableElem,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<QTableElem,int,&QTableElem::dummy> >
    >
> {};

int main()
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    {
        std::ofstream out("test.xml");
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(out);

        QTable obj;
        oa << make_nvp("graph", obj);
    }

    try {
        std::ifstream xml("test.xml");
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(xml);
        QTable obj;
        ia >> make_nvp("graph", obj); 
    } catch (boost::archive::archive_exception const& ae) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ae.code << ":'" << ae.what() << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
g++ -std=c++03 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_serialization && ./a.out
Error: 1:'position'
```

> **Note**: how the error is not actually with a closing element (W3C's well-formedness check would have told you that too)

Now, to fix the SSCCE just remove the inheritance:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d0a74416e643dc9)</kbd>**

```
typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
    QTableElem,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::member<QTableElem,int,&QTableElem::dummy> >
    >
> QTable;
```

I've done the same for your graph sample. It worked (as far as the tests exercised it at all):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="12">
<graph class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <V>20</V>
    <E>60</E>
    <vertex_property class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <property_value>0</property_value>
        <property_base class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <property_value class_id="3" tracking_level="0" version="0">
                <count>0</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
            </property_value>
            <property_base class_id="4" tracking_level="0" version="0">
                <property_value>0</property_value>
                <property_base class_id="5" tracking_level="0" version="0"></property_base>
            </property_base>
        </property_base>
    </vertex_property>
    <vertex_property>
        <property_value>0</property_value>
        <property_base>
            <property_value>
                <count>0</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
            </property_value>
            <property_base>
                <property_value>0</property_value>
                <property_base></property_base>
            </property_base>
        </property_base>
    </vertex_property>
    <vertex_property>
        <property_value>0</property_value>
        <property_base>
            <property_value>
                <count>0</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
            </property_value>
            <property_base>
                <property_value>0</property_value>
                <property_base></property_base>
            </property_base>
        </property_base>
    </vertex_property>
    <vertex_property>
        <property_value>0</property_value>
        <property_base>
            <property_value>
                <count>0</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
            </property_value>
            <property_base>
                <property_value>0</property_value>
                <property_base></property_base>
            </property_base>
        </property_base>
    </vertex_property>
    <vertex_property>
        <property_value>0</property_value>
        <property_base>
            <property_value>
                <count>0</count>
                <item_version>0</item_version>
            </property_value>
            <property_base>
                <property_value>0</property_value>
                <property_base></property_base>
            </property_base>
        </property_base>
    </vertex_property>
 ....
    <v>15</v>
    <edge_property>
        <property_value>
            <count>0</count>
            <value_version></value_version>
            <position object_id="_56"></position>
            <pointer class_id="-1"></pointer>
        </property_value>
        <property_base></property_base>
    </edge_property>
    <u>19</u>
    <v>5</v>
    <edge_property>
        <property_value>
            <count>0</count>
            <value_version></value_version>
            <position object_id="_57"></position>
            <pointer class_id="-1"></pointer>
        </property_value>
        <property_base></property_base>
    </edge_property>
    <u>19</u>
    <v>17</v>
    <edge_property>
        <property_value>
            <count>0</count>
            <value_version></value_version>
            <position object_id="_58"></position>
            <pointer class_id="-1"></pointer>
        </property_value>
        <property_base></property_base>
    </edge_property>
    <u>19</u>
    <v>13</v>
    <edge_property>
        <property_value>
            <count>0</count>
            <value_version></value_version>
            <position object_id="_59"></position>
            <pointer class_id="-1"></pointer>
        </property_value>
        <property_base></property_base>
    </edge_property>
    <graph_property></graph_property>
</graph>
</boost_serialization>
```

In case you want to review it, see: https://gist.github.com/sehe/093f823937486eb99d2f

Comment: Thanks for the penetrating reply. The problem has been solved. I have to say the usage of the serialization library is tricky to new users. There are so many subtle things needs attention.

Comment: I used inheritance to avoid circular dependent. But I already found ways to prevent that problem. This problem had been given me headache for a long time. Really thanks for the valuable reply!

Comment: I spent considerable amounts of time dissecting your huge sample and finding not only the cause, but also explaining it and how you could have located it yourself. (I even solved it for your particular code base). I'd like to think that counts as both _"this answer is useful"_ (upvote) and _"best answer to the question"_ (accept). Please consider the linked meta-question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: ^ @breadbread1984 consider selecting a best answer to help others find the solution to this question

Comment: @sehe, sorry for the late acceptance. I didnt notice the mark. :-P I will pay attention to this next time.